# Move mouse pointer on screen rotation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, embedded-linux, eglfs

I'm running PyQt app in kiosk mode without an X server.

OS and lib: `Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64`; `PyQt 5.15.4`; `eglfs` as back-end

The kiosk monitor will be rotated 90 degrees.
If I export the variable `QT_QPA_EGLFS_ROTATION=90` then the GUI rotates. However, the mouse pointer is not rotated on the screen (at least it seems that it is not rotated). The application reads the position of the mouse correctly, the x, and y coordinates are swapped, but the "drawn" cursor on the screen does not rotate, see the figure below

Cursor position at start:
[image: Cursor position at start]

If I move еру mouse down, real cursor also moves down, but the drawn cursor (arrow on screen) moves to the left.

Cursor position after mouse movement:
[image: Cursor position after mouse movement]

If there is a button at real cursor position, I can even click on it

So, how to rotate "drawn cursor"?

Comment: Also tried solutions from https://forum.qt.io/topic/76213/qt-mouse-pointer-rotation

Comment: Found something related. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68698 It may be not a solution but at least something. It seems that you can patch Qt when building it from sources and have a new env variable to rotate libinput